# mi proyecto vue no muestra los archivo png etc en un servidor flask

Tags: vue.js, flask

no se que hacer cuando creo mi proyecto vue aplico npm run build y tomo los archivo de dist y coloco los archivos en la carpeta static de mi proyecto flask me carga la pagina pero no me carga las archivo png que puedo hacer para arreglar eso

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cuando inicio mi proyecto con flask run no me lanza errores patentemente

```
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Mar/2024 18:24:41] "GET /obtenerapi HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Mar/2024 18:24:41] "GET /eliminar.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Mar/2024 18:24:41] "GET /carrovacio.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Mar/2024 18:24:41] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Mar/2024 18:26:01] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Mar/2024 18:26:01] "GET /static/assets/index-aK19yiDM.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Mar/2024 18:26:01] "GET /static/assets/index-LBofqSO8.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Mar/2024 18:26:01] "GET /obtenerapi HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Mar/2024 18:26:01] "GET /carrovacio.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Mar/2024 18:26:01] "GET /eliminar.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Mar/2024 18:26:01] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

mi proyecto es algo asi mas o menos

```
@app.route('/', defaults={'path': ''})
@app.route('/<path:path>')
def index(path):
    return render_template('carrito.html')
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes, lecturas recomendadas: https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour + https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Por otro lado, dale click derecho, inspeccionar elemento y mira la ruta que está siendo generada de esa imagen rota, luego editas la pregunta y agregas ese dato. Saludos.

Comment: desde el inspecionador si modifico la ruta del archivo me mostra el archivo png. como entonces como deberia configurar la ruta del archivo en mi proyecto vue si no puedo utilizar {{ url_for('static', filename='imagen.jpg') }} ?